# Why does it appear as though SSIS is not reading a connection string properly?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, ssis-2012

I am executing an SSIS package on a db server and receiving an error. I can execute it just fine on my local machine but when I try to execute it via a SQL Job I get the following:

```
Executed as user: <domain>\<user>. 
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.6020.0 for 64-bit  
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    
Argument ""CM.BackUpDB.ConnectionString";"Data "Source=<server>;Initial" "Catalog=<database>;
Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated" Security=SSPI;"" for option "parameter" is not valid.  
The command line parameters are invalid.  
The step failed.
```

It appears to me as though SSIS is splitting the connection string at the spaces instead of the semicolons. Why would it be doing that?

I am running SQL Server 2012. I do not have configuration files, nor am I dynamically generating the connection strings. They get configured in the SQL Job.

Comment: How are they configured in the SQL Job? Is this a SSIS step and you have connections defined in the advanced tab? It's important that you explain this, and in the process it's entirely likely you will solve your problem. When things like this happen to me I start with a known working case (i.e. whatever connection string you use in DEV), confirm that works in your job, then carefully compare it to a non working case.